# Regex not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

ok so let me explain the current situation:

i get some strings from COM1, i filtered this to show only the needed information and thus i have only strings like this:

```
NTF,IDAS,RXSTAT,IND,01-0100,01-0131,+,-63,81
```

now the problem is that in this example i need to get the number: 131 and ONLY that number,

i have tried to achieve this with Regex but with no success.

i have this as my Regex:

`Regex.Match(line, ",01-0100,01-0([0-9]{3})").Value.ToString()`

and expect that to return me the

`131`

but instead it returns:

`,01-0100,01-0131`

can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: print the group index 1 instead of index 0.

Comment: is the format always fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong group index. Group 0 is the entire match, group 1 is the value for the first group.

```
Regex.Match(line, ",01-0100,01-0([0-9]{3})").Groups[1].Value.ToString()
```

You could also name your group:

```
Regex.Match(line, ",01-0100,01-0(?<mygroup>[0-9]{3})").Groups["mygroup"].Value.ToString()
```

Oh, and as a group's value is always a string:

```
Regex.Match(line, ",01-0100,01-0(?<mygroup>[0-9]{3})").Groups["mygroup"].Value;
```

Comment: OR simply, `Regex.Match(line, "(?<=,01-0100,01-0)[0-9]{3}").Value.ToString()`